# Replace after a string - Before a character

Tags: c#, replace

I have a string like :

```
string str = "First Option: This is a text. This is second text.";
```

I can replace `This is a text.` with :

```
str = str.Replace("This is a text.", "New text");
```

But my constant word is `First Option:` and `This is a text` is not constant so how can replace the text after `First Option:` until occurring `.` (it means before `This is second text.`).
In this example the expecting result is :

```
First Option: New text. This is second text.
```

Comment: Either use `String.IndexOf` to get the indices and use the string lengths to calculate the position of the string to replace, or look into regular expressions (regex).

Comment: Use `Regex.Replace` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=First Option:)[^.]*", "New text");
```

`(?<=First Option:)[^.]*` matches a sequence of zero or more characters other than dot `'.'`, preceded by `First Option:` via a [*positive look-behind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not the shortest but if you want to avoid regular expressions:

```
string replacement = "New Text";
string s = "First Option: This is a text.This is second text.";
string[] parts = s.Split('.');
parts[0] = "First Option: " + replacement;
s = string.Join(".", parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up `.IndexOf()` and `Substring(...)`. That will give you what you need:

```
const string findText = "First Option: ";
var replaceText = "New Text.";
var str = "First Option: This is a text. This is second text.".Replace(findText, "");
var newStr = findText + str.Replace(str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(".") + 1), replaceText);

Console.WriteLine(newStr);
```